# StackOverflowError with PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, stack-overflow

I created a PreferenceActivity similar to the one in the Android ApiDemos.

I'm using this code to create the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.bridges_references);
    //setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
}
```

and this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Preferences">

    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="hasLoops"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:title="@string/title_hasLoops"
            android:summary="@string/summary_hasLoops" />

    <ListPreference
        android:key="width"
        android:defaultValue="7"
        android:summary="@string/summary_width"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/title_width"
        android:title="@string/title_width"
        android:entryValues="@array/size_values"/>

    <ListPreference
        android:key="height"
        android:defaultValue="7"
        android:summary="@string/summary_height"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/title_height"
        android:title="@string/title_height"
        android:entryValues="@array/size_values"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When I try to start the preference activity using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), BridgesPreferenceActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

I get a StackOverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1746)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
```

(too long to see what's actually causing it; it gets cut off)

This happens whenever I include a ListPreference or a EditTextPreference. The CheckBoxPreference works ok.

Sometimes it works once when I reduce the size of the array, but I get the StackOverflowError again as soon as I open the preferences a second time.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Similar code compiles and runs perfectly in the ApiDemos.

Kind regards,
Stephan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so apparently this was something to do with how I was saving the state of the calling Activity and not the actual preferences activity. I was saving a serialised object, which works fine when for instance the orientation changes, but not for some reason when I call a new activity.

I found this out after completely rewriting my preferences into a normal Activity and it still kept throwing the same error.

Oh well. *sigh*